# Transmission bytearray from Python to C and return it

Tags: python, c

I need fast processing of XOR bytearray, 
In a variant on Python

```
for i in range(len(str1)): str1[i]=str1[i] ^ 55
```

works very slow
I wrote this module in C.
I know C language very badly, before I on it wrote nothing.
In a variant

```
PyArg_ParseTuple (args, "s", &str))
```

everything works as expected, but I need to use instead of s s* because elements can contain embeded null, but if I change s to s* when calling python crash

```
PyArg_ParseTuple (args, "s*", &str)) // crash
```

Maybe some beginner like me want to use my example as a start to write something of his own, so bring all the information to be used in this example on Windows.
Parsing arguments and building values on page http://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/arg.html

**test_xor.c**

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* fast_xor(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    const char* str ;
    int i;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &str))
        return NULL;

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(str);i++) {str[i]^=55;};
    return Py_BuildValue("s", str);

}

static PyMethodDef fastxorMethods[] =
{
     {"fast_xor", fast_xor, METH_VARARGS, "fast_xor desc"},
     {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC

initfastxor(void)
{
     (void) Py_InitModule("fastxor", fastxorMethods);
}
```

**test_xor.py**

```
import fastxor
a=fastxor.fast_xor("World") # it works with s instead s*
print a
a=fastxor.fast_xor("Wo\0rld") # It does not work with s instead s*
```

**compile.bat**

```
rem use http://bellard.org/tcc/
tiny_impdef.exe C:\Python26\python26.dll
tcc -shared test_xor.c python26.def -IC:\Python26\include -LC:\Python26\libs -ofastxor.pyd
test_xor.py
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(str1)):` should be `for i in str1`

Comment: Except that as it appears to be written, it's writing back to the array. Though there is an error in that too: `str1=str1[i] ^ 55` should be `str1[i]=str1[i] ^ 55`, or more concisely `str[1] ^= 55`.

Comment: Thanks Henry Gomershal, corrected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need build an extension module to do this quickly, you can use NumPy. But for your question, you need some c code like this:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

static PyObject * fast_xor(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    const char* str;
    char * buf;
    Py_ssize_t count;
    PyObject * result;
    int i;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s#", &str, &count))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    buf = (char *)malloc(count);

    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        buf[i]=str[i] ^ 55;
    }

    result = Py_BuildValue("s#", buf, count);
    free(buf);
    return result;
}
```

You can't change the content of string object, because string in Python is immutable. You can use "s#" to get the `char *` pointer and the buffer length.

If you can use NumPy:

```
In [1]: import fastxor

In [2]: a = "abcdsafasf12q423\0sdfasdf"

In [3]: fastxor.fast_xor(a)
Out[3]: 'VUTSDVQVDQ\x06\x05F\x03\x05\x047DSQVDSQ'


In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: (np.frombuffer(a, np.int8)^55).tostring()
Out[6]: 'VUTSDVQVDQ\x06\x05F\x03\x05\x047DSQVDSQ'

In [7]: a = a*10000

In [8]: %timeit fastxor.fast_xor(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 877 us per loop

In [15]: %timeit (np.frombuffer(a, np.int8)^55).tostring()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 ms per loop
```

Comment: Yes, it works

Yet, how to make a similar function.

    b=bytearray('World')

    def change(b):

        for i in range(len(b)): b[i]=b[i]^55M

Comment: You can use bytearray API: http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/bytearray.html, to get the length and the char * buffer pointer.

Comment: Sorted out with `s*`: declare must `Py_buffer str`, parsing must `PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s*", &str)`, use: `str.len` - length of buffer, `str.buf` - data. Thank you all.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me except I needed to change the output type to 'y#' due to a UnicodeDecodeError.

result = Py_BuildValue("y#", buf, count);

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach is to use [`PyObject_GetBuffer`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects). The module below defines `fast_xor` for any object that supports the buffer protocol, and `fast_xor_inplace` for objects that have writable buffers, such as `bytearray`. This version returns `None`. I also added a 2nd `unsigned char`argument with a default value of 55.

Example:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> b = bytearray(s)
>>> fast_xor(s), fast_xor(s, 0x20)
('VUT', 'ABC')
>>> fast_xor_inplace(b, 0x20)
>>> b
bytearray(b'ABC')

>>> fast_xor_inplace(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
BufferError: Object is not writable.

>>> fast_xor(b, 256)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: unsigned byte integer is greater than maximum
```

Source:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *fast_xor_inplace(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *arg1;
    unsigned char arg2 = 55;
    Py_buffer buffer;
    char *buf;
    int i;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O|b:fast_xor_inplace", &arg1, &arg2))
        return NULL;

    if (PyObject_GetBuffer(arg1, &buffer, PyBUF_WRITABLE) < 0)
        return NULL;

    buf = buffer.buf;
    for(i=0; i < buffer.len; i++)
        buf[i] ^= arg2;

    PyBuffer_Release(&buffer);
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}

static PyObject *fast_xor(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *arg1;
    unsigned char arg2 = 55;
    PyObject *result;
    Py_buffer buffer;
    char *buf, *str;
    int i;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O|b:fast_xor", &arg1, &arg2))
        return NULL;

    if (PyObject_GetBuffer(arg1, &buffer, PyBUF_SIMPLE) < 0)
        return NULL;

    result = PyString_FromStringAndSize(NULL, buffer.len);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;

    buf = buffer.buf;
    str = PyString_AS_STRING(result);
    for(i=0; i < buffer.len; i++)
        str[i] = buf[i] ^ arg2;

    PyBuffer_Release(&buffer);
    return result;
}

static PyMethodDef fastxorMethods[] =
{
     {"fast_xor", fast_xor, METH_VARARGS, "fast xor"},
     {"fast_xor_inplace", fast_xor_inplace, METH_VARARGS, "fast inplace xor"},
     {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initfastxor(void)
{
    Py_InitModule3("fastxor", fastxorMethods, "fast xor functions");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, thanks. I begin to understand how use Py_buffer. But strangely, if i run examle as _example.py_ all work fine. If i run step-by-step in console - step `fastxor.fast_xor_inplace(b, 0x20)` cause crash python.

Comment: Define 'crash'? Do you get a segfault?

Comment: @Arty: If you use "s*", you'll have to check `buffer.readonly` and raise an exception manually. Otherwise you'll mutate an 'immutable' string.

Comment: Sorry, i only beginner C programmer. Probably not be able to see. I only see event about crash in eventlog and message box.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done very quickly using numpy. You're unlikely to get substantially faster hand-rolling your own xor routine in C:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: data = numpy.uint8(numpy.random.randint(0, 256, 10000))

In [3]: timeit xor_data = numpy.bitwise_xor(data, 55)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.4 us per loop
```

If you're using a big dataset (say 100 million points), it's favourably comparable to the times you have quoted for your code:

```
In [12]: data = numpy.uint8(numpy.random.randint(0, 256, 100000000))

In [13]: timeit xor_data = numpy.bitwise_xor(data, 55)
1 loops, best of 3: 198 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  char pybuffer[1024];
  ...
  PyArg_ParseTuple (args, "s#", pybuffer, sizeof(pybuffer));
```

Not sure what the buffer size requirements are - I've assumed 1024 is adequate.

Comment: I do not know in advance the size of the bytearray that will be passed. I have to get the size with a PyArg_ParseTuple

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `for`-loop. Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead, they are much faster:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: t = bytearray([random.randint(0,255) for i in xrange(10000)])

In [3]: u = bytearray([b^55 for b in t])
```

This is very fast:

```
In [11]: %timeit u = bytearray([b^55 for b in t])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 ms per loop
```

That's not really slow.  For 1 MB (10**6 bytes) it takes around 130 ms.

Of course using numpy as Henry Gomersall answered is the better solution.

Comment: My datasize 10-100 MBytes, time for you samples in my case 3-30 sec (with hints liked struct.unpack and zlib 0.6-6 seconds). in my example  on C i reached time 0.06-0.6 seconds. It's worth it.

Comment: My original timeit included the setup every time. See revised answer. 10 MB would take 1.3 s. Is that still worth it?

Comment: You can remove the inner lists and it will be even faster. `In [4]: %timeit u = bytearray(b^55 for b in bytearray(i for i in range(10000) if
 i < 255))
1000 loops, best of 3: 605 us per loop`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: your inner bytearray is only 255 bytes, not 10000. I'm guessing that is why it is faster. I've tested with and without the list, and with the list is faster.

Comment: @Roland Smith, your version is the fastest of the simple.But, in sample with C code result 0.006 sec/1MBytes. This is better than your result 0.13 sec/1MBytes. In pure python my best result 0.06 sec/1MBytes with struct.unpack